# Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I am using API to let user buy my ERC20 token. I am passing a signed message to the API and creating a contract instance in the backend. I am able to pass the message in the backend and I am also able to create a contract instance but during the transaction I am getting this error.

Front-end:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import { errors, ethers } from "ethers";
import TokenSwapAbi from "../contract/TokenSwap.json";

function TokenSwap() {
  const [numberOfTokensBuy, setNumberOfTokensBuy] = useState();
  const [numberOfTokensSell, setNumberOfTokensSell] = useState();
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState();
  const tokenSwapAddress = "0xEAF2a219D2223602486777f3fBF9e0fd1c321307";

  const getSignerattr = async () => {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const address = await signer.getAddress();
    return { signer, address };
  };

  const handleBuy = async () => {
    const signer = await getSignerattr();

    try {
      const numberOfTokens = numberOfTokensBuy; // Use the desired data as the message
      console.log("message1", numberOfTokens);
      await sendSignedMessage(numberOfTokens);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  //handling signature

  const sendSignedMessage = async (numberOfTokens) => {
    try {
      console.log("message2", numberOfTokens);
      const { signer, address } = await getSignerattr();
      const signature = await signer.signMessage(numberOfTokens);
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/blockchain/buy_token",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ numberOfTokens, signature, address }),
        }
      );

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const handleSell = async () => {
    const signer = await getSignerattr();
    const dat = {
      numberOfTokens: numberOfTokensSell,
      userAddress:
        "a631351e31813c2ec707bdded3821e7221f8514206862eb7c506d5182e9acdb3",
    };

    const requestOptionsSell = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(dat),
    };

    await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/blockchain/sell_token",
      requestOptionsSell
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error react", error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div id="tokenSwap" style={{ margin: "20%", width: "100%" }}>
      <div className="flex justify-center" style={{ widht: "100%" }}>
        <label>Buy Token </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setNumberOfTokensBuy(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <button
          className=""
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#3079AB", margin: "2%" }}
          onClick={handleBuy}
        >
          Buy
        </button>
        <br />
        <label>Sell Token </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setNumberOfTokensSell(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <button
          className="font-bold text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#3079AB", margin: "2%" }}
          onClick={handleSell}
        >
          Sell
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TokenSwap;
```

Backend API:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import {
  createTokenSwapInstance,
  provider,
} from "../../../helpers/contractInstance/tokenSwapInstance";
import { tokenSwapAddress } from "../../../config";

var signer;
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { numberOfTokens, signature, address } = req.body;
    
    //verifying signature
  signer = await verifySignature(numberOfTokens, signature, address);
  if(signer){
    const tokenSwapInstance = await createTokenSwapInstance(signer);
    //Checking if data is present
    const feePercent = 3.65;
    const tokenPrice = 0.0168;

    //Calculating total fee amount to pay
    const numberOfTokensinNum = Number(numberOfTokens);
    const numberOftokensinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(numberOfTokens));
    const pricePerToken = tokenPrice + tokenPrice * (feePercent / 100);
    const totalAmount = numberOfTokensinNum * pricePerToken;
    const totalAmountinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(totalAmount));
    
   // Buy tokens
    try {
      const tx = await tokenSwapInstance.functions.buyTokens(
        numberOftokensinWei,
        {
          value: totalAmountinWei,
          gasLimit: 5000000,
        }
      );
      await tx.wait();
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: "Transaction Successful." });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        msg: "Transaction Failed. Please try again.",
      });
    }
  }else{
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: "Invalid Signer" });
  }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: "Bad request." });
    }
}

//Verifying the signature
async function verifySignature(numberOfTokens, signature, address) {
  try {
    const signingAddress = await ethers.utils.verifyMessage(numberOfTokens, signature);
    signingAddress.toLowerCase() === address.toLowerCase();
    const signer = await provider.getSigner(signingAddress);
    return signer;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error3",error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error: bad response (status=400, headers={"date":"Thu, 15 Jun 2023 07:44:07 GMT","content-type":"application/json","content-length":"179","connection":"close","x-alchemy-trace-id":"07a11221b0167c7c3a84503295582e72","cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC","server":"cloudflare","cf-ray":"7d792f9daa64a920-MAA"}, body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":44,\"error\":{\"code\":-32600,\"message\":\"Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis\"}}", requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendTransaction\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x4c4b40\",\"value\":\"0x3ddd3690672000\",\"from\":\"0xb2165a8b792cf090f9ebde4206f1c76cbcb92546\",\"to\":\"0xeaf2a219d2223602486777f3fbf9e0fd1c321307\",\"data\":\"0x3610724e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000\"}],\"id\":44,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/QdetfdEykTy0OXPlBzrS7A1AlUBegoWd", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\gauth\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\gauth\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at C:\Users\gauth\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:275:36
    at step (C:\Users\gauth\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\gauth\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\gauth\OneDrive\Desktop\Blockchain\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'bad response',
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  status: 400,
  headers: {
    date: 'Thu, 15 Jun 2023 07:44:07 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '179',
    connection: 'close',
    'x-alchemy-trace-id': '07a11221b0167c7c3a84503295582e72',
    'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
    server: 'cloudflare',
    'cf-ray': '7d792f9daa64a920-MAA'
  },
  body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":44,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis"}}',
  requestBody: '{"method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"gas":"0x4c4b40","value":"0x3ddd3690672000","from":"0xb2165a8b792cf090f9ebde4206f1c76cbcb92546","to":"0xeaf2a219d2223602486777f3fbf9e0fd1c321307","data":"0x3610724e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000"}],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
  requestMethod: 'POST',
  url: 'https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/QdetfdEykTy0OXPlBzrS7A1AlUBegoWd'
}
```